# Why nautilus in background takes so much IO and CPU when login, and how to resolve that, or is that a bug?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, process, top, nautilus

I'm using Arch Linux for some time.

I find `nautilus` will be running automatically when I login because it's used for handling desktop's behavior. If I kill it, then trash icon and all other file's icons on desktop will be gone and right click menu will be incomplete. But recently I find it consumes too much IO and  CPU, shortly after I login. I don't know if that's a bug of `nautilus`, because I have been using Arch Linux for 6 months, and that issue never happened before.

Here is a slice of my `top` command's output. You can see that `nautilus` is a child process of `lightdm`

```
  395 root      20   0  331.8m   5.9m   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 S  `- lightdm                                                                              
  404 root      20   0  259.6m  42.5m   0.0  0.7   0:07.73 S      `- Xorg                                                                             
  549 root      20   0  256.1m   7.5m   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 S      `- lightdm                                                                          
  581 qs        20   0  563.2m  15.2m   0.0  0.3   0:00.16 S          `- gnome-session-b                                                              
  620 qs        20   0 2001.4m 193.8m   0.0  3.3   0:19.75 S              `- gnome-shell                                                              
  728 qs        20   0  952.5m  36.4m   0.0  0.6   0:01.13 S              `- gnome-settings-                                                          
  757 qs        20   0  579.9m  15.4m   0.0  0.3   0:00.05 S              `- zeitgeist-datah                                                          
  780 qs        20   0  773.7m  64.8m 130.5  1.1   1:14.09 S              `- nautilus
```

Answer (score -1):

check if all files unter ~qs/.cache/ belong to user qs.
A

```
    chown -R qs.qs ~qs/.cache
```

as root might fix your problem. It seems that nautilus still doesn't behave well when it can't write its thumbnails.